# How do I filter out <>c_DisplayClass types when going through types via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to create a unit test that makes sure all of my business classes (I call them command and query classes) can be resolved with Windsor.  I have the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Windsor_Can_Resolve_All_Command_And_Query_Classes()
    {
        // Setup
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
        IList<Type> classTypes = asm.GetTypes()
                                    .Where(x => x.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApp.DomainModel.Commands") || x.Namespace.StartsWith("MyApp.DomainModel.Queries"))
                                    .Where(x => x.IsClass)
                                    .ToList();

        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new SingletonLifestyleEqualizer());
        container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<HomeController>());

        // Act
        foreach (Type t in classTypes)
        {
            container.Resolve(t);
        }
    }
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
No component for supporting the service MyApp.DomainModel.Queries.Organizations.OrganizationByRegistrationTokenQuery+<>c__DisplayClass0 was found
```

I understand that `<>c__DisplayClass0` types are due to Linq being compiled, but how can I filter out these types without hardcoding the name in my Linq query?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would check each Type for the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx) that is put on these.

You can use [Type.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx), so the code would look something like this:

```
foreach (Type type in classTypes)
{
   if (type.IsDefined (typeof (CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false))
      continue;

   // use type...
}
```

Comment: You could use `type.IsDefined` to make life a bit simpler.

Comment: @Jon, Thanks!  I'll have to remember IsDefined... Much more succinct!

Comment: Code using Reflection that was running fine can be broken since VS2015! I have code that was returning the right Expression (a `List<T>`) from a MethodCall. Now it it is returning a `<>c__DisplayClass36_0).CS$<>8__locals1`. Note that this a `MemberExpression` (it was a `ConstantExpression` containing the list as value)). Now I have to follow this additional indirection and then get the value of a field of `CS$<>8__locals1` in order to get my list.

Comment: Like @Cameron MacFarland mentioned this does not work for nested classes.

Answer (score 16):

Apparently nested classes do not get the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute applied to them.

I whipped up this simple method to deal with this scenario.

```
bool IsCompilerGenerated(Type t) {
    if (t == null)
        return false;

    return t.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
        || IsCompilerGenerated(t.DeclaringType);
}
```

A class that exhibits this behaviour would look like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    void CreatesADisplayClass() {
        var message = "foo";

        Action outputFunc = () => Trace.Write(message);

        Action wheelsWithinWheels = () =>
        {
            var other = "bar";

            Action wheel = () => Trace.WriteLine(message + " " + other);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I had trouble on Mono with the accepted answer because Mono generates things a little differently (apparently). This works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the presence of the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute.